# I am able to read a file, but not able to see the result on Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

```
df01 = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/project/rio_bq_2019000000000000',lines=True)
```

No error for this line. But it has error on next line, I don't understand what happens here. I read it on google colab

```
df01
```

I got an error as following:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    337             if method is not None:
--> 338                 return method()
    339             return None
    340         else:

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_html(self, buf, encoding, classes, notebook, border)
    986         notebook : {True, False}, optional, default False
    987             Whether the generated HTML is for IPython Notebook.
--> 988         border : int
    989             A ``border=border`` attribute is included in the opening
    990             ``<table>`` tag. Default ``pd.options.display.html.border``.

AttributeError: 'NotebookFormatter' object has no attribute 'get_result'
        Building    Level  ...        lng                    localtime
0           TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.249902  2019-08-01 02:52:33.289 UTC
1           TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.250474  2019-08-01 02:52:35.488 UTC
2           TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.251573  2019-08-01 02:52:36.268 UTC
3           TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.249719  2019-08-01 02:52:41.537 UTC
4           TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.249737  2019-08-01 02:52:41.538 UTC
...          ...      ...  ...        ...                          ...
3372900     TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.250513  2019-08-25 10:21:01.483 UTC
3372901     TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.250169  2019-08-25 10:21:02.024 UTC
3372902     TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.250169  2019-08-25 10:21:02.026 UTC
3372903     TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.249944  2019-08-25 10:21:02.536 UTC
3372904     TPS1  Level 2  ... -43.249944  2019-08-25 10:21:02.536 UTC
```

I can see the data is imported in df01 as shown in the bottom of error output. But I can't use it. Why? how can I fix this?

In case you need, this is my sample data file

```
 {"Building":"TPS2","Level":"Level 3","ClientMacAddr":"8c:8e:f2:7d:2f:de","lat":-22.813377029213196,"lng":-43.247283256092494,"localtime":"2019-11-28 17:49:00.753 UTC"}
{"Building":"TPS2","Level":"Level 3","ClientMacAddr":"8c:8e:f2:7d:2f:de","lat":-22.813377029213196,"lng":-43.247283256092494,"localtime":"2019-11-28 17:49:00.753 UTC"}
{"Building":"TPS2","Level":"Level 3","ClientMacAddr":"00:27:15:00:10:1f","lat":-22.814628521677054,"lng":-43.24741506118599,"localtime":"2019-11-28 17:49:01.58 UTC"}
{"Building":"TPS2","Level":"Level 3","ClientMacAddr":"00:27:15:00:10:1f","lat":-22.814628521677054,"lng":-43.24741506118599,"localtime":"2019-11-28 17:49:01.58 UTC"}
```

I only have two lines before this

```
import pandas as pd
drive.mount("/content/drive")
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to be able to help you.  If the reading and de-JSONing of the input file isn't failing, then `df01` must consist of only lists, maps, and atomic data types.  There is no way that doing anything with that value should, on its own, lead to the execution of the code you're showing us.  So what are you doing with `df01`?  What is causing the code you show us to be executed?  Also problematic is that the attribute being referenced, `get_result`, is not found anywhere in the code that you're showing us, so it is hard to know why that is happening.

Comment: @CryptoFool You can see from the result after Attribute error in line 0-3372904. So I guess the notebook already read it, but output is an error. I only use drive.mount and import pandas as pd before this line. I can read my file in txt to show you what I contained in my file

Comment: That you can't execute `df01` by itself isn't something I'd worry about.  It's not valid Python, so it too is some kind of extension to the language or to the environment.  If you're thinking of the fact that it works in the REPL, that's true, but that's an extension of the REPL rather than part of the Python language itself. - With all that said, if it works for some variables but not others, then I'd call that a bug, and it's a bug in any case if it leads to an error like the one you're seeing.

Answer (score 7):

I still don't know what happened. But I just figure out myself

I can only make output in this case with print

Like df01 works well in jupyter, but in google lab I can only write in print(df01)

If you meet with this error

```
AttributeError: 'NotebookFormatter' object has no attribute 'get_result'
```

Please add print() in each line you are making an output

Comment: I'm having the same problem, thanks for sharing your solution. The only issue is that using print() makes Google Colab magic command `%load_ext google.colab.data_table` lose effect, it is a weird bug...

Comment: I had the same problem with Kaggle notebooks and I think I get what the problem is.I upgraded pandas to the latest version with a pip call within the notebook, but pandas library is autoloaded into the kernel even before an import. That is somehow causing a discrepancy. If I check pandas version after upgrading it, it's still the old one.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with colab
what I did was simply go to the Runtime and click on Restart Runtime

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue with one of my project. You simply have to restart your session.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on colab, this problem may be because of installing other packages. In my case, installing `pyLDAvis` package cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this type of error it's highly probable that the json file has format typo. Try to copy past your json file on a Online JSON parser (s.t. : http://json.parser.online.fr/) and see if there is a typo error.

Comment: No error with json, but I can only make an output with print(). I don't know why, I think google colab is jupyter notebook that allows output with df01 command directly

Comment: OK. Did you check the utf encofing format also ?

Comment: I can read the input into Pandas.  One thing to recognize, though, is is that your input isn't a valid JSON file because it contains multiple dictionary entities with no '[' and ']' around them.  JSON files always contain a single structure. - this doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem.  I assume that Pandas is able to deal with this as an extension to the standard JSON format

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with colab, this fixed:

```
!pip install -U pandas-profiling
```